# What is localhost/...?

Tags: localhost, http-status-code-403

When I go to http://localhost/... it gives me a **403 Forbidden: You don't have access to this resource**. If I go to http://localhost/.../enter-anything-here it gives me the same 403 forbidden error.  The same thing happens with 4, 5, or more periods.

The weird thing is that I don't even have a folder called `...` on my server. I'm suspecting it has to do with the `.` self-reference folder and `..` parent reference folder.

I'm running an Apache server with PHP, mySQL, and phpMyAdmin, all bundled under AppServ.

What is http://localhost/... and why does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

localhost is the local server on your workstation. when it gives the "403 - forbidden" alert, you are "looking" in an empty or restricted directory.

When you want to use localhost e.g. developing in PHP, you'll have to use something like XAMPP (virtual host). You will make a project-directory in the "htdocs"-folder, and if you navigate to "http://localhost/[*name of project-directory*]", you will see your project.

Watch this video for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6ENnaRotmo

Comment: But what is http://localhost/.../ for?  Meaning what is in it and why is it forbidden?

Comment: it kinda is what it says it's a local-host for hosting your local projects.
it's probably forbidden due to some settings on your computer